# Testing broken links in TestNG. How to ignore ConnectException and continue ahead in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I intend to ignore ConnectException and IOException exception and continue to test for broken links in a web page. The overall test result of the test in TestNG should show as pass. 
My code prepares a list of web elements which have href values. I then get a HttpURLConnection object to get the responseMessage. The code breaks when a connection to certain link fails with ConnectException. I have used @Test annotation with expectedExceptions. This helps in showing the final test result as pass but code after exception throw is not processed.

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = {ConnectException.class, IOException.class})
        public void testLinks() throws IOException, ConnectException
        {
              //Populate activeList here....
              int count = 0;  
              for(int ii=0; ii<activeList.size(); ii++) {

                url = new URL(activeList.get(ii).getAttribute("href"));
                connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

                System.out.println(activeList.get(ii).getAttribute("href"));
                connection.connect();
                connection.disconnect();
                System.out.println(++count); //this is not executed when Exception is thrown

            }
        }
    }
```

Expected: The line of code that prints "count" should be executed when ConnectException is thrown as well as final test result should be a pass.
 Actual: The count value is not printed.
 If I add try-catch to alter the flow then TestNG's excpetedException is not honored and the final test result is fail

Comment: You don't catch any `ConnectException`s so why do you expect the the JVM to ignore it?

Comment: I thought catching IOException and continue would help. Even catching ConnectException explicitly did not not solve the problem. Is there a way to continue with the for loop even after the exception is thrown

Comment: @DebanjanB. I was able to solve my issue by implementing the IMethodInvokedListener interface - override the afterInvocation method. The status of the test is forcefully promoted to pass status. The solution  as referenced by you as 'duplicate' didn't help.